# Facebook Connect with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, facebook-javascript-sdk, fbconnect, facebook-node-sdk

I am creating a web app with express.js and angular,js, where the client authenticates via facebook. For facebook authentication I use [facebook-node-sdk](https://github.com/amachang/facebook-node-sdk) to connect with facebook and retrieve details.

The code works well when authentication is made via a `url` redirect. But the same code returns no result when I send a `POST` request from client to invoke the same code

Server Code

```
app.post('/login', Facebook.loginRequired(), function(req, res){
  var result = {};
  req.facebook.api('/me', function(err, user) {
      console.log(user);
      if(user !== undefined){
        result.status = 1;
        result.name = user.name;
        res.contentType('json');
        res.write(JSON.stringify(result));
        res.render('index')
        res.end();
      }
      else{
        result.status = 0;
        result.name = "Error signing into Facebook";
        res.contentType('json');
        res.write(JSON.stringify(result));
        res.render('/')
        res.end();
      }
    });
});
```

I have no error when the above code is invoked. `console.log` shows:

> POST /login 302.

So is it possible to authenticate facebook via `POST` request or should it be always a direct URL request? If so any option to authenticate via POST?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? How did you use OAuth 2.0 authentication?

Answer (score 5):

If you've only just started and are going to use other Oauth authentications like gmail or twitter. I recommend using passport.js.

It is much simpler. http://passportjs.org/

Comment: No, i am targeted only towards facebook, since i need to retrieve user details after authentication. I doubt passport has tat option.

Comment: @de-bugged, Passport.js supports Facebook as an authentication provider: http://passportjs.org/guide/facebook/

Comment: Hi @Blackcoat, thnx for the link. Passport has options for authentication via GET. Im looking for Auth using POST.

Comment: @de-bugged  Is it possible to get facebook user profile without using passport/0auth or any other 3rd party plugin? If yes then how?